# ValueError('Invalid header name %r' % (header,)) ValueError: Invalid header name b'content-length:' .. Python

Tags: python

I need help if someone can help me with this code in python. I just want make auto making thread / creating list, I just checked in console the error say this. sorry if my grammar bad and thank you if someone help me to fix this code

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 29, in <module>
    requests.post(f"https://traderie.com/api/adopt_me/listings/create", data=body, headers=headers)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 117, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 234, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1293, in _send_request
    self.putheader(hdr, value)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 219, in putheader
    _HTTPConnection.putheader(self, header, *values)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1220, in putheader
    raise ValueError('Invalid header name %r' % (header,))
ValueError: Invalid header name b'content-length:'
```

Python Code:

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO

headers = {
  'authority': 'traderie.com', 
  'method': 'POST',
  'path': '/api/adopt_me/listings/create',
  'scheme': 'https',
  'accept': '*/*',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  'authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.MR5VEmRpjdplXZEtTrEy33FT7Y9HiJSbTGNaACeP060',
  'content-length:': '722',
  'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarypqN01X2kArSkOHBn',
  'cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.850822138.1642224893; _gid=GA1.2.556027755.1642224893; usprivacy=1---; ad_clicker=false; _pw_fingerprint=6818da724c1a866373d3104d2cd082e4; _gcl_au=1.1.628091182.1642224893; _hjid=cc106801-cff3-4156-afad-2b5845f96325; _hjSessionUser_2441420=eyJpZCI6IjQyMjdmMjVjLWEyMjItNTI1Ny04NjUwLWY3MmU1NjEyYjNlZiIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NDIyMjQ4OTMyMDAsImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; _hjSession_2441420=eyJpZCI6ImVkODE1MDc5LTYwNWItNDIzMC1iODUxLWZkOGRlNmM2YjM3MCIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NDIyMjQ4OTM0MzEsImluU2FtcGxlIjpmYWxzZX0=; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; _pw_audience_segments=["1","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]; __stripe_mid=a848c4df-5112-4afd-8bdd-2235857cc00abc7ef9; __stripe_sid=e1c6337b-f03f-4b93-8441-eb1d118cee58001fb3; _pw_audience_categories=["games_hardcore"]; _pbjs_userid_consent_data=3524755945110770; pwUID=369796799639702; __gads=ID=dcb867edd8f2877b:T=1642224926:S=ALNI_MYArRYYa1oDgieG9f1YFUuJjVv-oQ; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; G_AUTHUSER_H=2; _gat_UA-176465218-1=1; _gat_gtag_UA_176465218_1=1; cto_bundle=5p2Tj182VmVrbFhLNUFmS3lZNXllZnk2b1UzbkYwR0JhVUFUMSUyRnplYWd1QWh1VyUyQmlrJTJGYjlOTU1XdE1xb050NjhHJTJCajczQW1MeDNQSnRoRG9tM2UzeHN1blk5Z2pHYllDUlJLQUxVUHVDclp1JTJGT0N6cHluWjdjZzRGNVdRZFhqeUJiQmZSZlVORnI0dGlhdnV4MDQ2YnZFeVVnJTNEJTNE; playwirePageViews=16',
  'origin': 'https://traderie.com',
  'referer': 'https://traderie.com/adoptme/product/1276977709',
  'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'
}

body = '{"acceptListingPrice":false,"currencyGroupPrices":[],"diy":false,"endTime":"","free":false,"item":"1276977709","itemType":"pets","makeOffer":true,"needMaterials":false,"offerBells":false,"offerNmt":false,"offerWishlist":false,"offerWishlistId":"","selling":true,"standingListing":false,"stockListing":false,"touchTrading":false,"wishlist":"","amount":1,"properties":[{"id":1,"property":"Flying","option":true,"type":"bool","preferred":null},{"id":2,"property":"Rideable","option":true,"type":"bool","preferred":null},{"id":9,"property":"Age","option":"Full Grown","type":"string","preferred":null}]}'

requests.post(f"https://traderie.com/api/adopt_me/listings/create", data=body, headers=headers)
```

Comment: You can try to see the exception message, it says `ValueError: Invalid header name b'content-length:'`, look carefully you added an extra `:`, you just need to remove it, like this `content-type`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to see the exception message, it says `ValueError: Invalid header name b'content-length:'`, look carefully you have a `:` at the end of `content-type:`, you just need to remove it, like this `content-type`.

```py
import requests
from io import BytesIO

headers = {
    'authority': 'traderie.com',
    'method': 'POST',
    'path': '/api/adopt_me/listings/create',
    'scheme': 'https',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.MR5VEmRpjdplXZEtTrEy33FT7Y9HiJSbTGNaACeP060',
    'content-length': '722',
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarypqN01X2kArSkOHBn',
    'cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.850822138.1642224893; _gid=GA1.2.556027755.1642224893; usprivacy=1---; ad_clicker=false; _pw_fingerprint=6818da724c1a866373d3104d2cd082e4; _gcl_au=1.1.628091182.1642224893; _hjid=cc106801-cff3-4156-afad-2b5845f96325; _hjSessionUser_2441420=eyJpZCI6IjQyMjdmMjVjLWEyMjItNTI1Ny04NjUwLWY3MmU1NjEyYjNlZiIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NDIyMjQ4OTMyMDAsImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; _hjSession_2441420=eyJpZCI6ImVkODE1MDc5LTYwNWItNDIzMC1iODUxLWZkOGRlNmM2YjM3MCIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NDIyMjQ4OTM0MzEsImluU2FtcGxlIjpmYWxzZX0=; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; _pw_audience_segments=["1","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]; __stripe_mid=a848c4df-5112-4afd-8bdd-2235857cc00abc7ef9; __stripe_sid=e1c6337b-f03f-4b93-8441-eb1d118cee58001fb3; _pw_audience_categories=["games_hardcore"]; _pbjs_userid_consent_data=3524755945110770; pwUID=369796799639702; __gads=ID=dcb867edd8f2877b:T=1642224926:S=ALNI_MYArRYYa1oDgieG9f1YFUuJjVv-oQ; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; G_AUTHUSER_H=2; _gat_UA-176465218-1=1; _gat_gtag_UA_176465218_1=1; cto_bundle=5p2Tj182VmVrbFhLNUFmS3lZNXllZnk2b1UzbkYwR0JhVUFUMSUyRnplYWd1QWh1VyUyQmlrJTJGYjlOTU1XdE1xb050NjhHJTJCajczQW1MeDNQSnRoRG9tM2UzeHN1blk5Z2pHYllDUlJLQUxVUHVDclp1JTJGT0N6cHluWjdjZzRGNVdRZFhqeUJiQmZSZlVORnI0dGlhdnV4MDQ2YnZFeVVnJTNEJTNE; playwirePageViews=16',
    'origin': 'https://traderie.com',
    'referer': 'https://traderie.com/adoptme/product/1276977709',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'
}

body = '{"acceptListingPrice":false,"currencyGroupPrices":[],"diy":false,"endTime":"","free":false,"item":"1276977709","itemType":"pets","makeOffer":true,"needMaterials":false,"offerBells":false,"offerNmt":false,"offerWishlist":false,"offerWishlistId":"","selling":true,"standingListing":false,"stockListing":false,"touchTrading":false,"wishlist":"","amount":1,"properties":[{"id":1,"property":"Flying","option":true,"type":"bool","preferred":null},{"id":2,"property":"Rideable","option":true,"type":"bool","preferred":null},{"id":9,"property":"Age","option":"Full Grown","type":"string","preferred":null}]}'

requests.post(f"https://traderie.com/api/adopt_me/listings/create", data=body, headers=headers)
```